# How to export multiple column to excell from mathematica with each name at the sheet

Tags: export

I have a generated a dataset, name TRES. Its a data between wavelength vs intensity for different time. time varies from 0 ns to 5ns with an interval of 0.1ns. So there is a 51 no of set, and I want to export it in xlsx format. 
I have used the code:

```
TRESdata = {
  {{
    0., 0.0310218, 0.0323585, 0.0333725, 0.0337619, 0.0326912, 
    0.0315401, 0.0267583, 0.0223457, 0.0174552, 0.0130177, 0.00917527, 
    0.0071019, 0.00502596, 0.00212264, 0.000176303
  }},
  {{
    0., 0.0308938, 0.0322531, 0.0332925, 0.033701, 0.0326509, 0.0315132, 
    0.026754, 0.0223486, 0.0174704, 0.0130417, 0.00920224, 0.00712387, 
    0.00504376, 0.00213247, 0.000177189
  }}, 
  {{
    0., 0.0303927, 0.03184, 0.0329782, 0.0334615, 0.0324919, 0.0314067, 
    0.0267366, 0.0223598, 0.0175299, 0.0131354, 0.00930758, 0.00720961, 
    0.00511313, 0.00217079, 0.000180641
  }}
};
Export["TRESdata.xlsx", TRESdata]
```

In this process all datas are exported and when I open it via excel, then it opens. For each time, it creates a excel sheet. Its fine, but I have to assign the name of each sheet as "0ns","0.1ns","0.2ns" and so on instead of "sheet1","sheet2" etc. I can assign the name of sheet if there is 2-3 no of data using

```
Export[
  "TRESdata.xlsx",
  {
    "0ns" -> TRESdata[[1]],
    "0.1ns" -> TRESdata[[2]],
    "0.2ns" -> TRESdata[[3]]
  }
]
```

but how can I set the name of each sheet automatically for such a big data set?

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example of your current code to your question?

Comment: TRESdata={{0., 0.0310218, 0.0323585, 0.0333725, 0.0337619, 0.0326912, \
0.0315401, 0.0267583, 0.0223457, 0.0174552, 0.0130177, 0.00917527, \
0.0071019, 0.00502596, 0.00212264, 0.000176303}, {0., 0.0308938, \
0.0322531, 0.0332925, 0.033701, 0.0326509, 0.0315132, 0.026754, \
0.0223486, 0.0174704, 0.0130417, 0.00920224, 0.00712387, 0.00504376, \
0.00213247, 0.000177189},{0., 0.0303927, 0.03184, 
  0.0329782, 0.0334615, 0.0324919, 0.0314067, 0.0267366, 0.0223598, 
  0.0175299, 0.0131354, 0.00930758, 0.00720961, 0.00511313, 
  0.00217079, 0.000180641}}

Comment: This is some of the data which I have pasted from mathematica. I can assign the name of the as follows :Export["testTREStest.xls", {"0ns" -> TRESdata1, "0.05ns" -> TRESdata2}],but how can I assign the names for huge no of sheets?

Comment: Thank you. Note: You can use the "Edit" button to edit the content of your question. This way the code is more easily readable (be sure to use the appropriate formatting) and more visble to other users.

Comment: I've added your code (slightly edited) to the main question and rephrased it slightly - feel free to correct it if I made any mistakes

Answer (score 2):

You can create the list of sheet names using e.g. [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html), and use [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) to combine the names with the data:

```
(* generate the names. Note the use of 1/10 instead of 0.1 to avoid names like 0.ns *)
names = StringTemplate["``ns"] /@ Range[0, 2/10, 1/10]
(* {"0ns", "0.1ns", "0.2ns"} *)

(* export the data *)
Export["TRESdata.xlsx", Thread[names -> TRESdata]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help